# Applets on Wildfly/JBoss?

Tags: java, jboss, applet, wildfly

i wanted to ask ,do Wildfly or JBoss support java applets?I searched over the net and i found little information(probably because applets are not used anymore),i would like to know if someone has done this,without serious problems or restrictions.

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines for Stack Overflow and include some code that you've tried and errors/issues you're having. This is too broad. Thanks!

Comment: Anything that can serve HTML or other resources over the internet can 'support' applets.  *"..would like to know if someone has done this,without serious problems or restrictions."* Nope.  every single applet on the internet, however it is served, faces serious problems.  They need to be digitally signed using a valid (CA issued) code signing certificate.  Even then, browsers will typically put another prompt between the user and seeing the applet run (before it even gets to Java's own security prompts).  FF & Chrome are looking to remove **all support** for embedding applets.